# Dev vs Prod apps and Cloud Hosting

Tags: parse-platform

I have two apps, one for dev and one for prod.  I use parse.com hosting for my javascript app for both.

Is there any way to set the app id and secret key for Parse.initialize depending on which app the code is deployed in?  Meaning, Parse.initialize would get the dev key when deployed to the dev app and the prod key when deployed to the prod app?

Is the only option to keep setting the right keys in the code manually before deployment?

Comment: see 'config' https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Config.html   OR .. std js approach.... what is being used for the builds?  gulp , grunt , nothing. tools may outputs the parse.public directory including "dev.config.js" OR "config.js" with respective keys.  then thats input to the parse deploy..  parse deploy mytest   OR parse deploy myproduction. The build tool will have done the JS.config stuff where you have the parse keys.

Comment: https://github.com/focusaurus/express_code_structure/blob/master/app/config.js  sample mongo conf there. analog for parse.com prod vs dev keys